# What is the categorical feature in the lightgbm?

Tags: r, lightgbm

Recently, I am studying the LightGBM, and found that we should determine which features are the categorical features?

I know that for `character class`, they should belong to the `categorical features`, but if the feature is 'integer', does it belong to 'categorical feature'?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 9L), 
                 b = c("A", "B", "D", "A", "C"),
                 c = c(2.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.5, 6.7))
dt

sapply(dt, class)

          a           b           c 
  "integer" "character"   "numeric"
```

We can see that `b` should be 'categorical feature', how about `a`?

Also if the the feature belongs to `factor class`, is it a categorical features?

In general, given the large dataset, what is the best way to identify all the categorical features used for LightGBM?

Thanks!

Comment: The `factor` class has its root and is perhaps specific to R. Factors (levels) are integer as in dummy coding but dummy variables are not always factors. What does category mean? It depends but almost always is synonymous with the `factor` class. It also depends on what question you are answering and what type of "regression" you are performing. [Here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R/reference/lgb.Dataset.set.categorical.html), lightbgm defines categorical feature as a char.

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon Can you point me out where says: "lightbgm defines categorical feature as a `char.`"

Comment: **categorical_feature 
categorical features. This can either be a character vector of feature names or an integer vector with the indices of the features (e.g. c(1L, 10L) to say "the first and tenth columns").** `a` in your example can be a factor e.g. for binary data (again, "dummy coding")